# Get all array data with a certain string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I want to get all the array data where keys has the characters 'ch' from the start. How do I get it?

```
Array ( [editpostid] => 0 [editpostcat] => 1 [ch114] => on [ch115] => on )
```

The keys of the data may vary as the numbers come from the record id's from the database.

how do I place all the data with 'ch' in the start of keys on to a separate array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this

```
<?php
$arr = array('ch'=>10,'abch'=>20,'ch23'=>45);
$newarr=array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
if(substr(strtolower($k),0,2)=='ch')
{
array_push($newarr,$v); // Make use of this if you just need the values
//$newarr[$k]=$v; // Uncomment this and comment above statement, if you need the keys too 
}
}
print_r($newarr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 45
)
```

Comment: `that has the characters 'ch' from the start.`: This will get those which have `ch` anywhere. Unless that's what they want, because they list contradictory requirements in the question

Answer (score 1):

```
$charray=array();
foreach($yourarray as $key=>$value){
        if(preg_match("/^ch/",$key)){
            $charray[$key]=>$value;
        }
    }
//$charray is the new arrayas you asked for
echo implode(',',$charray);
```

refer **[official documentation for preg_match](https://www.php.net/preg_match)** for more information

Comment: @sectus.. Thanks for letting me know.. i have modified it :)

Comment: No need for regex here, avoid wherever possible. http://bradt.ca/blog/stop-avoiding-regular-expressions-damn-it/